# Python pandas plot linechart with data points

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I would like to plot a linechart based on column `A`. Based on Column `sig` I would like to add some markers to the chart A:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(120), columns=list('A'))

data['sig'] =   np.NaN
data['sig'] =  np.where((data['A'] > 1),      data['A'], data['sig'] )

data.plot(grid=True)
plt.show()
```

I tried to add `markevery=data['sig']` to the `plot()` statement, but it gave me several errors. Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not plot directly in matplotlib?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(120), columns=list('A'))

data['sig'] =   np.NaN
data['sig'] =  np.where((data['A'] > 1),      data['A'], data['sig'] )

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(data["A"])
ax.scatter(data.index, data["sig"])
```